# Excel Worksheet_Change not working

Tags: excel, vba

Not able to get the Worksheet_Change event to run and not sure why.  The cell B5 is part of a PivotTable and when that value changes, need to call and run a different sub (and that sub is working)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'MsgBox ("run private")
Dim WatchRange As Range
Dim IntersectRange As Range
Set WatchRange = Range("b25")
Set IntersectRange = Intersect(Target, WatchRange)
If IntersectRange Is Nothing Then
    'MsgBox ("do nothing")
Else
    'MsgBox ("run macro")
    Call ChangeTitle
End If
End Sub

Sub ChangeTitle()
'
'
Dim Mytitle As Range
Set Mytitle = Worksheets.Item("Current").Range("b25")

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PVTRatingTech").PivotFields("title").CurrentPage = _
    Mytitle.Text


End Sub
```

Comment: Is it because you are trying to run code when `B5` changes but your code has `B25` coded? Is this a simple typo?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I tested the code and this code works.

Paste this in a **Module**

```
Public Oldval As Variant
Public NewVal As Variant
```

Paste this in a **Workbook** Code Area

```
'~~> Replace Sheet1 with the actual sheet name
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Oldval = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Value
End Sub
```

and paste this in the **Worksheet** Code Area

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    NewVal = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Value
    If Oldval <> NewVal Then
        Oldval = NewVal
        ChangeTitle
    End If
End Sub

Sub ChangeTitle()
    Dim Mytitle As Range

    Set Mytitle = Worksheets.Item("Current").Range("b25")

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PVTRatingTech").PivotFields("title").CurrentPage = _
    Mytitle.Text
End Sub
```

Save and close your workbook and open it again. Now when you refresh your Pivot if B5 changes then "ChangeTitle" will run.

Hope this is what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

As Remnant has already pointed out, you do have a typo. Not sure if you meant B5 or B25.

There is nothing wrong with your code. If B25 is in the Target, then your `ChangeTitle` macro will run. If the macro isn't running, then simply B25 isn't in the Target.

On a side note, you could reduce the code in your change event to

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("b25")) Is Nothing Then Call ChangeTitle

End Sub
```